# Running nobody (or dynamic user) with CAP_NET_RAW in systemd

Tags: networking, systemd, linux-capabilities

I want to run service with cap_net_raw capabilities but with no any interaction with filesystem and/or other processes. My program will use raw sockets and normal sockets (for API), stdout/err for logging and that's all.

I want to write systemd.service file to do this, but I couldn't produce a proper combination for `DynamicUser`, `User` and `CapabilityBoundingSet`.

My (non-working) unit looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my daemon (%I)
ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/daemon/%i.conf
Wants=network-online.target
BindsTo=daemon.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/etc/daemon
EnvironmentFile=/etc/daemon/%i.conf
ExecStart=/usr/bin/daemon ${OPTIONS}
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_RAW
ProtectSystem=true
ProtectHome=true
RestartSec=5s
Restart=on-failure
User=daemon-%i
Group=nobody
DynamicUser=true
[Install]
WantedBy=daemon.target
```

How can I configure dynamic user 'nobody' together with `CAP_NET_RAW`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need:

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_RAW
```

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580597/what-is-the-difference-between-ambientcapabilities-and-capabilityboundingset) about the difference between AmbientCapabilities and CapabilityBoundingSet, as well as the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).